# cant get day and month from date object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cant get the month and day from the date object like this : "2009/12/30"

The error which gives in the console is: TypeError: created_at.getMonth is not a function

```
    function search(){
    var value = $('#box').val();
    var array=[];
    var dateArray = [];
    var datesString;
    if (value!==""){$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=value&rpp=5",
      function(data){

   $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
       var user=item.from_user;
      var created_at=item.created_at;
      var n=created_at.toString();
       var month=n.getMonth();
      var day = n.getDate();
      var year = n.getFullYear();
      var created=month+day+year;
      array.push({date:created,username:user});
     });
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?
thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that `n.getMonth()` returns an error? Nowhere above are you calling `created_at.getMonth()`. `n.getMonth()` correctly returns an error because `n` is the String representation of a Date object.

Comment: i tried removing the month ,day and year variables and used only the var month=created_at.getMonth(); but know it stops the page from rum=nning and gives error in the script tap over firebug

Comment: it gives error on the previous line where is var user=item.from_user; i dont know why

Comment: yes and it gives error : created_at.getMonth is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't support `Date` values directly, so Twitter is serializing each `created_at` value as a `String` that you'll first have to parse:

```
var user = item.from_user;
var created_at = new Date(item.created_at);
```

Then, you can use [`Date` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/#Methods_2) to get information from it:

```
var month = created_at.getMonth();
var day = created_at.getDate();
var year = created_at.getFullYear();
```

Also, if `created` is intended to be a `Date` at midnight, try this instead:

```
var created = new Date(year, month, day);
```

Comment: so after how do i combine the values together?

Comment: @anjelos The line starting with `array.push` should be fine as you have it. Or, is that not what you meant?

Comment: @anjelos Your current line for setting `created` is adding, not concatenating, as each `Date` method returns a `Number`. If you want concatenation, you can force it by "adding" to a string: `var created = '' + month + day + year;` or `var created = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;`